Por que a atribuição não cria uma cópia, mesmo com "mode.copy_on_write" habilitado?
Pelo que entendi, habilitando o mode.copy_on_write, df e df_copy deveriam ser cópias independentes.
Ou seja, as mudanças em df_copy não afetariam mais df e vice-versa. Só que isso não está funcionando como esperado, inclusive quando verifico o ID ambos compartilham o mesmo objeto.
Estou usando Python 3.9 e Pandas: 2.4.
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('mode.copy_on_write', True)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C': [7, 8, 9]})

df_copy = df

df['A'] = [10, 20, 30]

print("Original DataFrame após modificação:")
print(df)
print("\nReferenced DataFrame após modificação no original:")
print(df_copy)

df_copy['B'] = [40, 50, 60]

print("\nOriginal DataFrame após modificação no referenciado:")
print(df)
print("\nReferenced DataFrame após sua própria modificação:")
print(df_copy)

print(id(df))
print(id(df_copy))

Saída:
Original DataFrame após modificação:
    A  B  C
0  10  4  7
1  20  5  8
2  30  6  9

Referenced DataFrame após modificação no original:
    A  B  C
0  10  4  7
1  20  5  8
2  30  6  9

Original DataFrame após modificação no referenciado:
    A   B  C
0  10  40  7
1  20  50  8
2  30  60  9

Referenced DataFrame após sua própria modificação:
    A   B  C
0  10  40  7
1  20  50  8
2  30  60  9
1719736171584
1719736171584


  ____________________________________
/ Eu não altero a forma como o Python \\
\\ funciona                            /
  ------------------------------------
         \   ^__^ 
          \  (oo)\_______
             (__)\       )\/\\
                 ||----w |
                 ||     ||
    

A configuração copy_on_write (CoW) afeta apenas o comportamento dos objetos dentro do Pandas, sem modificar o comportamento padrão da linguagem Python.
Quando você faz df_copy = df você está basicamente atribuindo um novo nome ao objeto original, por isso apontarão para o mesmo ID na memória (veja "sequências imutáveis" e "sequências mutáveis" aqui). Esse é o comportamento padrão da linguagem, por isso ao modificar a configuração do Pandas não fez com que mudasse isso.
A configuração de CoW é útil em outro cenário um pouco mais específico no Pandas, que é quando você precisa acessar/modificar uma (ou mais) colunas do seu dataframe. Por exemplo:
df_copy = df['B']

Nesse caso você não precisou "copiar" o dataframe inteiro, mas só uma coluna específica. Com a configuração de CoW desativada (definida como falsa), qualquer alteração que realizar em df_copy afetará também o DF original.
df_copy.iloc[0] = 40

print(df)  # Veja que o 40 aparece em df também
#     A   B  C
# 0  10  40  7
# 1  20   5  8
# 2  30   6  9


Nota: perceba que o comportamento se aplica no uso do método iloc (ou análogos) pois eles modificam o objeto em si. O mesmo comportamento não se aplicará caso você atribua novos valores ao objeto, como df_copy = [40, 50, 60], justamente porque nesse caso você estará criando outro objeto com o mesmo nome, não afetando o objeto original.

Ao definir a configuração CoW como verdadeira, ao fazer df_copy = df['B'] o Pandas irá criar uma cópia do objeto antes de retorná-lo, fazendo com que todas as alterações na cópia não afetem o objeto original.
pd.set_option('mode.copy_on_write', True)

df_copy.iloc[0] = 40

print(df)  # Veja que o 40 não aparece em df
#     A  B  C
# 0  10  4  7
# 1  20  5  8
# 2  30  6  9

